After upgrade Magento 2.4.6 to 2.4.7-p3 product quick view image appears small
I recently upgraded my Magento store to version 2.4.7-p3, and since then, I’ve noticed an issue with the Quick View Popup. The product images inside the popup are displayed much smaller than expected.
Here's what I’ve found and tried so far:
1.What I’ve Checked:

Verified the product image dimensions and quality in the media library.
Inspected the CSS and found that the image is being constrained by some styling, but overriding it in the theme didn’t fully resolve the issue.

Additional Details:
Magento Version: 2.4.7-p3
Theme: Custom theme based on Alothemes/gecko
Quick View Popup worked fine before the upgrade.
Quick view image before an upgrade :

Quick view image after an upgrade :

How can I resolve the issue of small product images in the Quick View Popup in latest version?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
